# Остановка потока через определенное время Android

Tags: android, многопоточность

Коллеги, необходимо принудительно завершить поток если он работает больше 6 секунд.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PressFindD.this, "", "Пожалуйста, подождите, выполняется расчёт");
    startCalculating.setClickable(false);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            if (!checkNotNull()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                startCalculating.setClickable(true);
                return;
            }
            preparationCalculateD();
            if (main()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PressFindD.this, OutputResultsFindD.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            startCalculating.setClickable(true);

        }
    }.start();
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге методом, сам дошел, может не так изящно, но всё же

```
Thread mainThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            if (!checkNotNull()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                startCalculating.setClickable(true);
                return;
            }
            preparationCalculateD();
            if (main()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PressFindD.this, OutputResultsFindD.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            startCalculating.setClickable(true);
        }
    };
    //
    Thread delayedStopMainTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    sleep(6000);
                    if (mainThread.isAlive()) mainThread.interrupt();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    startCalculating.setClickable(true);
                    
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    delayedStopMainTread.start();
    mainThread.start();
    mainThread.interrupt();
```